# Remote Desktop to WAN address from inside LAN doesn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I have a router opened up to allow Remote Desktop to one of the machines.  It works if I try to connect from outside the network.  If I however am inside the LAN and try to connect using the WAN IP address it doesn't work.  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have [NAT reflection](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=43) enabled if your router/firewall supports it. This allows you to access internal servers by public IP. Otherwise, you need to use private IP addresses when accessing internal servers.

Comment: Why won't it let me access internal machines via the public IP?  Why doesn't it just go out to the internet and back in again?

Comment: @Craig.. the reason for the behavior you see is exactly as Khaled mentions. Most inexpensive routers for not provide this capacity. Some do but don't enable it by default.

Comment: @CraigJ: Public IPs are directed to the default gateway which is your router. Then, the router will forward them to the outside if not configured to route them back in.